# using jquery validate accept methods with ie - any polyfills

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, file-extension

the jQuery validate has an extra plugin called accept

http://jqueryvalidation.org/accept-method

what this allows you to do is validate file types on an upload form for example

so you could have a bit of code that looks like

```
$("#addNewDocumentForm").validate({
rules: {
     inputDocument: { required: true, accept: "png|jpe?g|gif|pdf"  }
},
messages: {
     inputDocument: "File must be PDF, DOCX, JPG, GIF or PNG"               
},
submitHandler: function(e) {
      ...
```

the problem is using this in ie 8 or 9 because while it will do the required part it will not do the accept bit as it uses the file API part of HTML5

I was wondering if anyone has come across any similar issues? any if they found any polyfills for it etc?

Comment: Wrong rule:  `accept` is only for `mime-type`.  You need to use `extension` if you want to validate the _file extension_.  BTW- you also have a `?` stuck inside your `JPG` extension.

Comment: thanks jpe?g allows for .jpeg or .jpg and does work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making one of two possible errors:

1. using the wrong rule for validating the file extension.
2. using the wrong parameters for validating the `mime-type`.

The `accept` method is only for validating by `mime-type`.

Assuming you want to validate by *file extension*, then you'll need to use the `extension` method.

Read and compare the documentation for the two methods: [`extension`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/extension-method/) and [`accept`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/accept-method/).

Both `accept` and `extension` are part of [the plugin's own `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js).

```
$("#addNewDocumentForm").validate({
    rules: {
        inputDocument: {
            required: true,
            extension: "png|jpg|gif|pdf"
        }
    },
    messages: {
        inputDocument: "File must be PNG, JPG, GIF or PDF"               
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        ...
```